# How to display a generated image in postman flow?

Tags: postman, postman-flows

I have a simple yet tricky question about postman flow.
**How to display a generated image in the output block ?**

When I run the request that create the image in classique mode my image is correctly rendered in the response body
[image: generated Qr code]

But when I call the same request in flow, the image is not displayed
[image: postamn flow with image]
While a the link of an image is displaying the image correctly.

The endpoint that return the image is flagued with the good return type

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/generateQR/{id}", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_KAMINOAIN')")
    public @ResponseBody byte[] generateQRCode(@PathVariable("id") Long id) throws Exception {
        Clone clone = getOne(id);
        return barCodeService.generateQRCodeImage(clone.toString());
    }
```

I know that flow is a feature still in developement, so maybe it's not yet possible.
But if anybody know how to render the image, it'will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some time I have found some work around

Now my service don't send a byte array but a base64 encoded string that represent it

```
@GetMapping(value = "/generateQR/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_KAMINOAIN')")
    public @ResponseBody String generateQRCode(@PathVariable("id") Long id) throws Exception {
        Clone clone = getOne(id);
        var qrcode = barCodeService.generateQRCodeImage(clone.toString());
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(qrcode);
    }
```

Then in postman flow, in place of displaying the image just after getting it, I added a template bloc
[image]

and after this bloc I can render my image in a comment bloc
[image]